# Python requests doesn't read the payload data

Tags: python, python-requests, request, http-post

I'm trying to scrape the products data of this website using API requests [https://www.tilersonline.com.au/search-results?q=](https://www.tilersonline.com.au), I have noticed that whenever you scroll all the way down in the page while you keep watching the network traffic you will noticed that they are calling an API POST request, the request name is search, I have tried to implement the same request in Python but I keep getting this response back:

> {"error":{"message":""user" is required;"t_client" is required"}}

This is the code I'm trying at the moment :

```
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    payload = {
        "user": {"uid": "SAm1D4bXW7iX1AKg", "sid": "FAmjHdWalmysHdsO", "persist": True, "exist": True},
        "t_client": 1892366204062,
        "key": "463dcab6-6df4-4293-969b-745f5f81e10d",
        "limit": 24,
        "offset": 24,
        "filters": [], "q": ""
    }
    content = requests.post("https://api.findify.io/v4/463dcab6-6df4-4293-969b-745f5f81e10d/search", data=payload)
    print(content.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using json instead of data in the post request, like this:

```
content = requests.post("https://api.findify.io/v4/463dcab6-6df4-4293-969b-745f5f81e10d/search", json=payload)
```

It did work for me. This is the response context:

```
{"meta":{"q":"","suggestion_limit":5,"item_limit":3,"rid":"a-394b7463-68dc-4a27-bc45-9b2d1fb7f67c"},"suggestions":[{"value":"tile cutter"},{"value":"rubi"},{"value":"sigma"},{"value":"grout"},{"value":"mixer"}],"items":[{"availability":true,"color_variants":5,"created_at":1661358377000,"selected_variant_id":"TEN","image_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/full/TEN.jpg?1692342220","id":"TEN","item_group_id":"TEN","price":[38,41.5,46],"product_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/tenax-adhesive","quantity":14,"thumbnail_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/thumb/TEN.jpg?1692342220","title":"Tenax Adhesive","custom_fields":{"brand_icon":["/assets/webshop/cms/04/204-1.jpg?1671664458"]},"reviews":{},"stickers":{"in-stock":true,"out-of-stock":false}},{"availability":true,"color_variants":1,"created_at":1661299200000,"selected_variant_id":"SI-ART2B3","image_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/full/SI-ART2B3.jpg?1692342220","id":"SI-ART2B3","item_group_id":"SI-ART2B3","price":[369],"product_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/sigma-tile-cutter-art-2b3-660mm","quantity":24,"thumbnail_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/thumb/SI-ART2B3.jpg?1692342220","title":"Sigma Tile Cutter Art-2B3-660mm","custom_fields":{"brand_icon":["/assets/webshop/cms/38/138-1.jpg?1671591876"]},"reviews":{},"score":{"original":1,"boosted":31.042022705078125,"popularityBoost":31.042022705078125},"pinned":false,"stickers":{"in-stock":true,"out-of-stock":false}},{"availability":true,"color_variants":1,"created_at":1661299200000,"selected_variant_id":"IQ-228","image_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/full/IQ-228.jpg?1692342220","id":"IQ-228","item_group_id":"IQ-228","price":[855],"product_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/iq-power-tools-228-cyclone-180mm-dry-table-saw","quantity":183,"thumbnail_url":"https://www.tilersonline.com.au/assets/thumb/IQ-228.jpg?1692342220","title":"IQ Power Tools 228 Cyclone 180mm Dry Table Saw (with special Bonus kit)","custom_fields":{"brand_icon":["/assets/webshop/cms/39/139-1.jpg?1671515741"]},"reviews":{},"score":{"original":1,"boosted":27.996126174926758,"popularityBoost":27.996126174926758},"pinned":false,"stickers":{"in-stock":true,"out-of-stock":false}}],"content":{}}
```